# Excel formula with OR and AND and possible lookup

Tags: excel, if-statement, statements

I need to write a formula as follows:

```
A   B   C   D   E   User ID    Name
x   x   x       x     abc      AIDA S
```

If a=x OR b=x AND c=x or d=x or e=x, Yes. Or in english, if you have a or b, and c, d, or e then "yes".  On top of that, Aida might be repeated else where in the spreadsheet with a different set of parameters than shown above.  Can I add a vlookup or something else to say if Aida S has a or b, and c, d, or e anywhere in the worksheet than "yes"?  Thanks so much.

Comment: Chart didn't show up well, it should have column headers of a, b, c, d, e, user ID, and name.  Underneath should be x, x, x, blank, x, abc, Aida S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formulas you'll need to use are `IF`, `OR`, and `AND`. Assuming you're familiar with `IF`, `AND` and `OR` can be used together to evaluate multiple conditions. In your case, your formula could look something like this:

`IF(AND(OR(A1="x",B1="x"),OR(C1="x",D1="x",E1="x")),"YES","NO")`

For your other conditions, you can move the `OR` conditions as you need, or add/remove conditions within the `OR`/`AND` statements.